# Finding the model matrix, $P$, knowing eigenvectors and eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The exercise is the following:

> It is known that a certain $\small{2\times2}$ matrix $A$ has two eigenvalues:
>
> - $\lambda=3$, which has a corresponding eigenvector $v_{3}=(\frac{3}{2};-1)$; and
> - $\lambda=\sqrt{2}$, which has a corresponding eigenvector $v_{\sqrt{2}}=(-1;1)$.
>
> Calculate $P$, such that $$P^{-1}\cdot A\cdot P=\begin{pmatrix}
> \sqrt{2} & 0\\ 0 & 3 \end{pmatrix}$$

---

I know that, if $A=\begin{pmatrix}
a & c\\
b & d
\end{pmatrix}$, then:

$\begin{pmatrix}
a-3 & c\\
b & d-3
\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{3}{2} \\
-1 
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
0 
\end{pmatrix}$

$\begin{pmatrix}
a-\sqrt{2} & c\\
b & d-\sqrt{2}
\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}
-1 \\
1 
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
0 
\end{pmatrix}$

This way, I obtain $A=\begin{pmatrix}
9-2\sqrt{2} & 9-3\sqrt{2}\\
-6+2\sqrt{2} & -6+3\sqrt{2}
\end{pmatrix}$, so now all there's left to do is to try $P=\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & \frac{3}{2}\\
1 & -1
\end{pmatrix}$ and $P=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{3}{2} & -1\\
-1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$ and check which one gives me the desired diagonal matrix (which, by the way, is the first option)

My question is: isn't there a MUCH easier way to do this?

Comment: it's basically a matrix of eigenvectors...

Comment: I don’t get it... I know P is a matrix of eigenvectors, but I can either write it with $v_{3}$ as the first column or the second...

Comment: The order of the eigenvectors in $P$ has to match the order of the eigenvalues in the diagonal matrix.

Answer (score 1):

The simpler way is to note that the eigenvectors of a matrix $A$ are the basis in which the transformation is represented by a diagonal matrix $D$ with the eigenvalues as diagonal elements. And if
$$
P^{-1}AP=D
$$
than
$$
A=PDP^{-1}
$$

---

For the diagonal form

$$D=\begin{pmatrix}
\sqrt{2} & 0\\
0 & 3
\end{pmatrix}$$

the ''basis'' matrix (with, as columns, the corresponding eigenvectors) is

$$
P=\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 3/2\\
1 & -1
\end{pmatrix}$$

so we can easily  find $P^{-1}$ and calculate $A=PDP^{-1}$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how does that help?

Comment: I added something to my answer. I hope it's useful.

Comment: That way, I'll have found two possible sets of entries for A: one where P is the one you mention and the other where P has the columns are swapped.

The objective of the exercise is to calculate P (not A), but there two options for P and I was wondering if there was an easier way to assess which one is the correct one without having to calculate A and then trying both

Comment: The first column of $P$ are the eigenvectors of the first eigenvalue in the diagonal matrix, the second column are the eigenvectors of the second eigenvalue.... .. is this the answer you are looking for?

Comment: Oh my god, I can't believe it was that simple... Thank you so much!